Can we notify / warn answerers of ongoing contest questions
This puzzle https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/128822/specific-triangle-sides-in-a-grid is from the current USAMTS Round 2 https://www.usamts.org/contest/problems/ , deadline December 2, which I did not know when I answered it on Oct 19.
I also unknowingly answered the Round 1 puzzle https://files.usamts.org/Problems_36_1.pdf , and the question seems to have been deleted.
I feel bad for answering ongoing contest problems. I will stop answering no-attribution puzzles in the future.

I only found out about the Round 2 puzzle because I have an old unclosed browser tab on it. Can we notify answerers of ongoing-contest problems to alert them to their behaviour?


What do you mean by "notify answerers of on-going contest problems?" We don't have an automatic way of detecting contest problems. If I notice in time (i.e. when the question is undeleted and has an undeleted answer) I'll usually comment on the answer to tell them what we've found out about the attribution.

Also, this seems like two completely separate feature requests: 1) for people to do a particular thing in the future 2) for an action to be taken on some specific questions right now. Note that the action to do right now isn't even the same thing as what you want done in the future.

@bobble thank you for replying. By "notify answerers of on-going contest problems" I mean when you delete a question for being an ongoing contest question, can you (or an automated system) also notify any answerer that they answered an ongoing contest question and the question is now being deleted? This may slowly discourage people from answering no-attribution questions.

That's a request for the diamond moderators, since they're the ones who delete such questions. As far as I know, there isn't a way to indicate why you're deleting a post (other than spam), so there's no automated way to do this either. If that's what you're mainly interested in, please [edit] to remove the second unrelated question. You can post the second question separately

Related/possible dupe: Questions from on-going contests
